# What is the current growth rate of the bitcoin blockchain size month by month in 2020?

Tags: blockchain, blocksize

I'm looking to get a VPS to host a btc full node and would like to know how much space I should get and what is the current Bitcoin blockchain growth rate on a monthly basis?

Comment: Ok nevermind. Currently BTC blockchain takes up 300GB of space. Any online VPS would cost at least $50-$70 a month for just the 300GB space this isn't accounting for the growth of the btc blockchain of about 25% a year or 30GB or so a year. As an application developer this doesn't make sense to spend so much on building on top of BTC just for fun that requires a full node. I've finalized and just decided to just go with blockchair.com for the time being.

Comment: You can run a node in pruning mode, reducing the storage costs dramatically.